# Getting the next autonumber value specific to a connection (concurrency)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a data entry page that displays a generated case number as:

[image]

This number is the next available autonumber for the primary key of the table. It was retrieved using:

```
String sql="SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT \r\n"
                    + "FROM information_schema.tables \r\n"
                    + "WHERE table_name = 'dataentrytbl' \r\n"
                    + "AND table_schema = DATABASE();";
            stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()) reply=rs.getInt("AUTO_INCREMENT");
```

Everything works perfect. The system is online, multiple users are using the data entry page and getting concurrency problems. The reason is all of them are getting the same generated auto id so when they click the ENTER button, an error is thrown.

Question: is there a way to generate a unique value for the autonumber primary key together with the connection? So if there are 5 users accessing the page simultaneously, is there a way to generate 5 different values for each of them?

Comment: switch to uuids

Comment: The PK of a table is not supposed to be displayed in any UI. If you need to display it in the UI use a secondary column for this purpose only, **NEVER the pk**. You can use a sequence to generate this number; I've also seen a "centralized REST service".